# Compare two columns using pandas and update changed values and append missing values

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, comparison

I have two different csv dataframe files `Test1.csv` and `Test2.csv`, I would like to match the 'id' column in `Test1.csv` to 'id' column in `Test2.csv`, and append missing 'id' values into `Test2.csv` and update missing values.

Shortly Append **False** values, and update **True** values in `Test2.csv`

`Test1.csv`

```
   No    Price(Op)    Price(Cl)   id   
   1     1200         500         a01 
   2     1400         500         a02
   3     1500         600         a03
   4     1800         500         a04
   5     1000         500         a05
   6     1570         800         a06
   7     1290         500         a07
   8     1357         570         a08
```

`Test2.csv`

```
   No    Price(Op)    Price(Cl)   id
   1     1200         500         a01 
   2     1500         500         a03
   3     1450         500         a02
   4     1800         500         a04
   5     1200         500         a05
```

`Desired Output:` `Test2.csv`

```
   No    Price(Op)    Price(Cl)   id   
   1     1200         500         a01 
   2     1500         600         a03
   3     1400         500         a02
   4     1800         500         a04
   5     1000         500         a05
   6     1570         800         a06
   7     1290         500         a07
   8     1357         570         a08
```

I tried To Loop Over with if statement

```
ds = pd.read_csv('Test1.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('Test2.csv')
for index, row in ds.iterrows():
    if row['id'] in df['id']:
        df['Price(Op)'].iloc[idx] = val['Price(Op)']
        df['Price(Cl)'].iloc[idx] = val['Price(Cl)']
        #What If index Are Different, How Program will know index of same id on other file
    else:
        df.append(ds.iloc[idx]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly different approach.

1. Merge df's `No` and `id` columns with all values from `ds` using right merge so that all values from `ds` are used, but order is kept from `df`.
2. Merge `df` order (`No`) with `ds`s order (`No_ds`) using combine_first
3. Cleanup dup `No_ds` column, sort by `No` and reorder columns to desired order.

```py
import pandas as pd

ds = pd.DataFrame({'No': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5,
                          5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8},
                   'Price(Op)': {0: 1200, 1: 1400, 2: 1500,
                                 3: 1800, 4: 1000, 5: 1570,
                                 6: 1290, 7: 1357},
                   'Price(Cl)': {0: 500, 1: 500, 2: 600,
                                 3: 500, 4: 500, 5: 800,
                                 6: 500, 7: 570},
                   'id': {0: 'a01', 1: 'a02', 2: 'a03',
                          3: 'a04', 4: 'a05', 5: 'a06',
                          6: 'a07', 7: 'a08'}})

df = pd.DataFrame({'No': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
                   'Price(Op)': {0: 1200, 1: 1500, 2: 1450,
                                 3: 1800, 4: 1200},
                   'Price(Cl)': {0: 500, 1: 500, 2: 500,
                                 3: 500, 4: 500},
                   'id': {0: 'a01', 1: 'a03', 2: 'a02',
                          3: 'a04', 4: 'a05'}})

# Merge df with ds
new_df = df[['No', 'id']] \
    .merge(ds,
           on='id',
           how='right',
           suffixes=['', '_ds'])
# Merge No Columns Together
new_df['No'] = new_df['No'].combine_first(new_df['No_ds']).astype(int)
# Drop Dup No Column, Sort and Reorder Columns
new_df = new_df \
    .drop(columns=['No_ds']) \
    .sort_values('No')[['No', 'Price(Op)', 'Price(Cl)', 'id']]

print(new_df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
   No  Price(Op)  Price(Cl)   id
0   1       1200        500  a01
2   2       1500        600  a03
1   3       1400        500  a02
3   4       1800        500  a04
4   5       1000        500  a05
5   6       1570        800  a06
6   7       1290        500  a07
7   8       1357        570  a08
```

Answer (score 2):

outer `Merge` both the DF's filter the required columns and then drop `suffix` -

```
merged_df = df2.merge(df1, how = 'outer', on='id').filter(regex=r'id|.*_y')
merged_df.columns = merged_df.columns.str.rstrip('_y')
```

**Note -** Check the type of merge that you wanna perform `rigth` or `outer`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `continue` keyword and update your `df` if the `index` is not in `df`.

```
ds = pd.read_csv('Test1.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('Test2.csv')
for _, ds_row in ds.iterrows():
    for idx, df_row in df.iterrows():
        if ds_row['id'] == df_row['id']:
            df['Price(Op)'].iloc[idx] = ds_row['Price(Op)']
            df['Price(Cl)'].iloc[idx] = ds_row['Price(Cl)']
            continue
        #What If index Are Different, How Program will know index of same id on other file
        df = df.append(ds.iloc[idx]
```